# Unable to run test, too many files open

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, jestjs

I am now unable to run tests, I was able to run the basic sum.js test on jests tutorial page, but am unable to test my react code. I've seen on other sites that moving the node 4.x fixes the issue, but not for me.  Any help is appreciated.

C:\wamp\www\ccRelaunchWorkspace>node -v
v4.3.0

I am running windows 7

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "*",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "*",
    "babel-preset-react": "*",
    "jest-cli": "*",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "~0.14.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "./node_modules/babel-jest",
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "./node_modules/react",
      "./node_modules/react-dom",
      "./node_modules/react-addons-test-utils"
    ]
  },
```

error:

```
Using Jest CLI v0.7.0
Error reading file: `C:\wamp\www\ccRelaunchWorkspace\node_modules\babel-preset-e
s2015\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters\node_modules\babel-t
raverse\node_modules\babel-code-frame\node_modules\chalk\node_modules\ansi-style
s\package.json`
C:\wamp\www\ccRelaunchWorkspace\node_modules\jest-cli\node_modules\node-haste\li
b\loader\ResourceLoader.js:88
      throw err;
      ^

Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'C:\wamp\www\ccRelaunchWorkspace\node_m
odules\babel-preset-es2015\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters
\node_modules\babel-traverse\node_modules\babel-code-frame\node_modules\chalk\no
de_modules\ansi-styles\package.json'
    at Error (native)
 npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have completely remove all modules, and moved all of my modules into `dependencies`, instead of having some in `devDependencies`, and removed the version numbers on anything jest related and replaces the versions with `*` and then ran `npm install`